# MongoDb Atlas: Where is the tlsCAFile when using their Managed X509 certs for users?

Tags: mongodb, go, ssl, sdk, mongodb-atlas

I have created a user in MongoDB Atlas and it uses an Atlas managed x509 certificate for authentication.  When I use the uri that MongoDb Atlas provides in Studio3T and select the cert that Atlas provided when I configure the connection in Studio, the authentication works properly.

But...

When I take the same uri and try to use it in my golang mongo sdk app, I cannot get authenticated.  It demands that I provide the tlsCAFile, but Atlas has not provided one to me.  Where can I find this file for using their managed x509 certs?

Thank you for your time and help!
Mike

Comment: I may have found the answer at the following link... I need to verify whether it works when I return to the office.
https://www.mongodb.com/docs/atlas/reference/faq/security/